# How to connect old LG Optimus L5 2 cellphone screen to a Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: raspberry-pi, driver, display, cellphone, touchscreen

I extracted the screen from an old LG Optimus L5 2 phone. The screen model is allegedly LM400MN1A. I want to use it as a display for my Raspberry Pi 4B, but I don’t know which part of the board is the driver nor whether I can use it myself, and the end of the screen’s cable has a connector I can’t recognize, like a concave rectangular prism with about 24 pins. Here are some pictures for reference:

The screen:

[image]

One side of the board (connection to the screen in the bottom-left corner):

[image]

The other side of the board:

[image]

Comment: It might be impossible to find out how to connect it. Also, you already asked this on Superuser.SE an hour ago.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.